# By using Filamentphp, why does my TextInput won't automatically load any data from database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

So I am working on a project using laravel and filamentphp 3.x.
I experienced problems when I wanted to change the order record where the price should appear automatically.
I had the Orders table and Products table, and the price value is stored in Products table.

products table:

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(User::class);
            $table->foreignIdFor(Products::class);
            $table->string('order_code')->unique();
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity');
            // $table->decimal('unit_price', '10', 2);
            $table->string('status')->default('pending');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

orders table:

```
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('features');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('price');
            $table->dateTime('start_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_visible')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('is_featured')->default(false);
            $table->longText('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Order models:

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Products::class);
    }
```

OrderResource.php:

```
Group::make()->schema([
    Section::make()->schema([
        Select::make('products_id')
            ->label('Product')
            ->options(Products::query()->pluck('name', 'id'))
            ->native(false)
            ->reactive()
            ->afterStateUpdated(fn ($state, Set $set) =>
            $set('price', Products::find($state)?->price ?? 0)),
        TextInput::make('quantity')
            ->numeric()
            ->default(1)
            ->required()
            ->live()
            ->dehydrated(),
        TextInput::make('price')
            ->label('Price')
            ->prefix('IDR')
            ->disabled()
            ->dehydrated()
            ->numeric()
            ->required(),
        Placeholder::make('gross_amount')
            ->label('Total Price')
            ->content(function ($get) {
                return $get('quantity') * $get('price');
            }),
    ])
])
```

I tried to make some change to TextInput::make('price') to this:

```
TextInput::make('price')
    ->label('Price')
    ->prefix('IDR')
    ->disabled()
    ->dehydrated()
    ->numeric()
    ->required()
    ->default(function ($record) {
        return $record->product ? $record->product->price : 0;
    }),
```

but it still not return any price value.

and then I tried to add a price column to the order table but why do I have to add a price column if I already have price in the product table?

Comment: You have relation in Order for `Product` so you can display using that

Comment: try to uncomment this line `->afterStateUpdated(fn ($state, Set $set) =>
            $set('price', Products::find($state)?->price ?? 0)),` and give a shot

Comment: @MiteshRathod did you mean to comment the line? because based on my code that I provide, I'm not commenting that line

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant to say comment that line. Sorry

Comment: @MiteshRathod so, i have commented the line but it makes the placeholder not work. That line i commented is a function to set gross_amount placeholder and price field automatically updated